# FSCalendar hide today image when selected others

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, fscalendar

FSCalendar hide today image when selected others dates .

Here I have a DIYCell for FSCalendarCell and got a ImageView on it .

only when it's today the imageView will show .

and when selected other dates , I want hide today's imageView .

Like When I selected 8th and today is 6th . then hide imageView on 6th and show what's on 8th.

Comment: if you want to hide today's image view then you can use below property "calendar.today = nil" where calendar is equal to object of FSCalendar

Comment: @DixitRathod I have tried but its not working , today's imageView is still there .

Comment: @DixitRathod     self.calendar.today = nil;
    [self.calendar reloadData]; I have tried this too . none of these worked .